# how can i see a list of all SMS sent in my account?

Tags: twilio

I have a twilio account for sending SMS.
However, i need guidance on how to see a list of SMS sent, at what time and to which phone number. I have tried to navigate through the different menus in my account but i dont see any option to see the sent messages list or an option to export it to Excel. Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [their API doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message), the [Messages list](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) resource represents the set of messages sent from and received by an account.

With it, you can access the media (SMS) list subresource, ex [from their doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) :

`/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages/{MessageSid}/Media`

You'll retrieve all the parameters of the media as shown [in this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information). Up to you then to transform & export these data into excel.

Comment: many thanx. they also gave me this link: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/messages